# Bower dependency watcher

Tags: open-source, dependencies

I've heard of [David](http://david-dm.org), which watches the Node.js dependencies of a project and gives you a badge that you can embed on any GitHub page. Does anyone know of a similar watcher for [Bower](http://bower.io)? It should also provide a similar badge.

Comment: [libraries.io](https://libraries.io/) is another to check out but I don't believe that it provides badges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have a look at an application called Gemnasium. It supports quite a few languages including [Bower](https://gemnasium.com/bower) and [Node.js](https://gemnasium.com/npms). It parses your project's dependencies and notifies you when new versions are released or they need to be updated. It also provides you with badges and has [a guide](http://support.gemnasium.com/knowledgebase/articles/560841-how-to-add-the-gemnasiun-badge-to-my-project-readm) on how to incorporate them into your GitHub page. It has free & paid plans that you can use as well.

## [Gemnasium](https://gemnasium.com/) ([freemium](https://gemnasium.com/pricing))

> Gemnasium monitors your Ruby / PHP / Node.js / Javascript / Bower / Python project dependencies and alerts you about updates and security vulnerabilities. Your project might be using a dangerous dependency, we will notify you as soon as advisories are public and affect your projects.
>
> With Gemnasium, start reducing your technical debt today, and keep your project in shape!
>
> [image: Gemnasium Badge on GitHub]
>
> [image: Gemasium UI]

Answer (score 1):

There is also VersionEye. It too supports quite a few languages including [Node.js](https://www.versioneye.com/Node.JS) and Bower. It also has dependency badges with [a guide](http://blog.versioneye.com/2013/05/08/versioneye-dependency-badges/) on how to incorporate them. Note that this *does not* have a free plan to use.

## [VersionEye](https://www.versioneye.com) ([commercial](https://www.versioneye.com/pricing))

> VersionEye notifies you about outdated dependencies in your software projects. Nowadays software projects are based on many open source and self developed components. Checking manually for updates for these components is a very time consuming task and not fun at all! VersionEye notifies software developers about outdated dependencies in their projects. That way they can save a lot of time and focus on development.
>
> [image: Badge example]
>
> [image: Badge Code Example]